# matplotlibでplotの線の色を変更する方法

Tags: python, matplotlib

pythonを用いて、plotの線の色を変更したいです。
一般的な、「赤」「青」などの一色の線に変更するやり方はわかりますが、
線の途中である値に対して、線が赤になったり青になったりすることは可能でしょうか?

以下に自作したscriptを示して、具体的になにを行いたいかを示します。

```
from pylab import *
import random
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

movements = np.arange(200)

##Storage information
traceXs, traceYs = [], [];
Speeds = [];
Times = [];

for trial in range(0, 1):
    ###moment information
    cur_x, cur_y = 0, 0;
    nxt_x, nxt_y = 0, 0;
    s = 100.0;

    traceXs.append(cur_x);
    traceYs.append(cur_y);
    Times.append(0);
    Speeds.append(s);

    for t in movements:
        """
            Section for trace movements
        """
        ###trace position of movement
        r = random.randint(0, 3)
        if r == 0:
            nxt_x, nxt_y = cur_x+1, cur_y;
        elif r == 1:
            nxt_x, nxt_y = cur_x, cur_y+1;
        elif r == 2:
            nxt_x, nxt_y = cur_x, cur_y-1;
        elif r == 3:
            nxt_x, nxt_y = cur_x-1, cur_y;

        traceXs.append(nxt_x);
        traceYs.append(nxt_y);

        #update the position for next step
        cur_x, cur_y = nxt_x, nxt_y;


        """
            Section for trace movements
        """
        direction = random.randint(0, 1)
        r2 = random.random();
        if direction == 0:
            s += r2;
        elif direction == 1:
            s -= r2;
        Times.append(t);
        Speeds.append(s);


plt.figure()
plt.plot(traceXs, traceYs)

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(Times, Speeds, s=1, c=Speeds, cmap='bwr')

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(traceXs, traceYs, s=1, c=Speeds, cmap='bwr')
plt.colorbar()

x_range = 1.1*max(abs(min(traceXs)), max(traceXs));
y_range = 1.1*max(abs(min(traceYs)), max(traceYs));
range_ = max(x_range, y_range)

plt.xlim(-range_, range_)
plt.ylim(-range_, range_)

plt.show()
```

上記のscriptはrandom walkをトレースする図（図１）を作成します。
この図１にスピードの変化を表す色をつけたいです。(実際にはrandom walkは一定のスピードで進むのは分かっています。)

図2では移動スピードを別に計算して、それを作図したものを示します。（色はスピードの早さにより変わるようになっています。）

図2で示した色を、図１でも表示したいのですが、作成方法がわかりません。

自分で行えたのは、図３で示したようにscatter plotを使用して、それっぽくは表示してありますが、やはり線でつながれた状態で、色をつけたいです。

もしご存知の方がおられましたら、ご教授をお願いします。

Comment: 肝心の「図1～3」が無いようですが、貼り忘れでしょうか？

Comment: @cubick さん、`plt.figure()` が3つあるのでその3つではないでしょうか。

Comment: @nekketsuuu コード中で出力している図を指していたわけですね、完全に勘違いしていました。

Comment: 英語版 Stack Overflow 上の類似質問です：[how to plot one line in different colors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17240694/5989200)

Comment: すみません。コード内に図の数字をコメントしておけば、よりわかりやすかったです。英語版のサイトを知りませんでした。勉強になります。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

スピードの変化に基づいて線の色を変える方法ですが、[こちら](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multicolored_line.html) が参考になるかと思います。
で、上記を参考に質問に挙げられたコードを修正すると

```
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

movements = np.arange(200)

##Storage information
traceXs, traceYs = [], [];
Speeds = [];
Times = [];

for trial in range(0, 1):
    ###moment information
    cur_x, cur_y = 0, 0;
    nxt_x, nxt_y = 0, 0;
    s = 100.0;

    traceXs.append(cur_x);
    traceYs.append(cur_y);
    Times.append(0);
    Speeds.append(s);

    for t in movements:
        """
            Section for trace movements
        """
        ###trace position of movement
        r = random.randint(0, 3)
        if r == 0:
            nxt_x, nxt_y = cur_x+1, cur_y;
        elif r == 1:
            nxt_x, nxt_y = cur_x, cur_y+1;
        elif r == 2:
            nxt_x, nxt_y = cur_x, cur_y-1;
        elif r == 3:
            nxt_x, nxt_y = cur_x-1, cur_y;

        traceXs.append(nxt_x);
        traceYs.append(nxt_y);

        #update the position for next step
        cur_x, cur_y = nxt_x, nxt_y;


        """
            Section for trace movements
        """
        direction = random.randint(0, 1)
        r2 = random.random();
        if direction == 0:
            s += r2;
        elif direction == 1:
            s -= r2;
        Times.append(t);
        Speeds.append(s);

points = np.array([traceXs, traceYs]).T.reshape(-1,1,2)
segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)
norm = plt.Normalize(min(Speeds), max(Speeds))
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('bwr')
lc = LineCollection(segments, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
lc.set_array(np.array(Speeds))
lc.set_linewidth(2)
plt.gca().add_collection(lc)
plt.xlim((min(traceXs),max(traceXs)))
plt.ylim((min(traceYs),max(traceYs)))
plt.show()
```

のように書けるかと思います。

やっていることはほとんどサンプルと同様なので、説明はいらないと思いますが、

1. 図１の各ラインをセグメントに分割
2. 上記のデータより Colormapを適用した LineCollection を作成
3. セグメント毎の Speed を LineCollection.set_array() で渡す
4. axesにたいして、add_collection() にて LineCollection を追加

となります

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ありがとうございます！質問をしたあと、たまたま同じサイトを見つけて、奮闘しておりました。サンプルコードもお示しいただき、ありがとうございました！